# SQL if in where

Tags: sql, if-statement

I want to write a sql query like this, below the logic:

```
when nn not null then dn like 'id=$nn$%' 
when user_id = $usrid$
when field1 not null then field1= $wid;
```

I'm writing it for splunk search.

I want to compare 3 three inputs and modify the query to current input which is not null.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a CASE statement. I suggest you look search for _sql case statement_, If that doesn't solve your problem please edit your question and provide some more information to make it clearer what you're trying to do.

Comment: Use case statement

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to incorporate these into your `where` conditions, with some small adjustments to what you wrote above.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE (nn IS NULL OR dn like 'id=' + @nn + '%')
  AND (user_id = @usrid)
  AND (field1 IS NULL OR field1 = $wid)
```

For the first and third conditions, we invert the logic on the null check and `OR` it with the actual criteria. Thus for example, `field1=$wid` is only evaluated when `field1` is `not null` (since it if it null, the first part of the criteria - `field1 IS NULL` - evalutates to true.

I also changed your `$param$` syntax to the more common `@param`, though this may vary based on your sql flavor.

Finally, I do not think that a `case` statement is appropriate here (as recommended by some commenters) because you are looking to filter different columns in different ways, not output differently for one column based on critera (for which you would generally use a `CASE` statement).

Comment: I used an OR in the query and it ran successfully. Thanks for effort.